# Календарь jQuery

Tags: jquery, календарь, javascript

Хочу добавить календарь на сайт, как в jQuery, только с праздниками. например нажал 1 января и там где-нить показывает "Новый год" и т.д. так можно сделать?

Comment: Можно! Разрешаю.

Comment: ну спасибо... что разрешили... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

бегло просмотрел документацию по **Datepicker** и обнаружил событие [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect)

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        if(dateText=="01/01/2012")
            alert("Happy New Year!");
    }
});
```

думаю, некоторый костыль на основе этого события можно написать

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
inline: true,
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
if(dateText=="01/01/2012")
alert("Happy New Year!");
}
if(dateText=='01/01/12')
style.backgroundImage='url(C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Рабочий стол\jQuery\ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png)';
});
});
</script>
скажите пожалуйста, где здесь ошибка? из консоли: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: лишняя фигурная скобка, внимательно посмотрите.

Comment: тут нет лишних фигурных скобок. тут if не нравится браузеру почему-то... может быть второый раз нельзя... как же сделать?

Comment: да, скобки на месте. но ``if`` не браузеру не нравится, а js-парсеру - второй ``if`` никак не вписывается в допустимый синтаксис, либо перенесите его в функцию, либо вынесите за приделы объявления объекта

Comment: сделал так (два скрипта):  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function(){  
$('#datepicker').datepicker({  
inline: true,  
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {  
if(dateText=="01/01/2012")  
alert("Happy New Year!");  
}  
});  
});  
</script>  
<script>  
$('#datepicker').datepicker({  
if(dateText=='01/01/12')  
style.backgroundImage='url(C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Рабочий стол\jQuery\ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png)';  
});  
</script>  
из консоли:  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (  
(неожиданный символ "(")

Comment: по-моему консолью вы умеете пользоваться, она вам ясно подсказывает, что где-то что-то не так со скобками, попытайтесь сами разобраться с проблемой, это вам очень пригодится в жизни, если уж совсем тяжко, то задайте ещё один вопрос, потому что разбирать неотформатированный код в комментах - это ещё то извращение. И ещё, попытайтесь хоть немного почитать по js, чтобы не писать подобные глупости в коде.

Comment: не ну я правда не понимаю почему скобка лишняя... вот так же должно быть: "if()", не "if(" и не "if)"  
почему у вас правильно, а у меня нет, хотя пишем мы одно и тоже??? пишет что неправильно вот это - if(dateText=="01/01/2012") (когда я пишу второй раз (в другом скрипте), хочу фон поменять)  
если что извините, я js знаю плохо...

Answer (score 0):

> как в jQuery

говорит о том что вы не разбираетесь абсолютно ни в чем, по этому помогать Вам смысла нет, берете гугл и начинаете искать "Календарь jQuery"

Comment: разбираюсь, js плохо знаю только. календарь я сделать могу, но мне нужен с праздниками

Comment: @johniek_comp, по-моему, это бредовый стереотип. Простота jQuery никаким образом не может говорить о незнании человека других языков/способов. Если автор вопроса видел подобный календарь на jQuery, то именно такая формулировка правильная и нечего искать в этом его незнание.

Answer (score 0):

Такого **нет** — пишите сами!

Comment: жаль......

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте [clndr.js](https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR)